# Best way to store text in an application / game without 'hardcoding'?

Tags: java, string

While I'm sure this question has probably been asked before, my research has left me fruitless. Thus, I've decided to pose the question: "What is the best way to store text in an application / game without 'hardcoding'?".

I've dabbled with Android in the past, and was quite fond of the way it used xml to store [String resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html). However, I'm currently developing a desktop game based on the [libGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) and don't have such functionality natively available to me (as far as I'm aware, at least). I guess I could define class constants for the various Strings, but I feel like that would be a 'smelly' solution...

Any guidance would be greatly, greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: You can probably create an interface to store constants and the variables declared in Interface are implicitly public static final. You can use property file as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a properties file as a resource. If your properties file is called `gamestrings.properties` and lives in your source directory in the same package as the current class (within `src/main/resources` for maven), you can do as follows:

```
ResourceBundle rsrc = ResourceBundle.getBundle("gamestrings");
```

`GameClass` would need to be the name of one of your classes, so that you can get a classloader to load the resource.

You can then use `rsrc.getString(String key)` to get a property as a string.

Here is an example of a properties file:

```
MainMenu.welcomeMessage=Welcome to my game!
MonsterGenerator.weakMonsterName=Mosquito
```

You are encouraged to name the keys after the classes that will use them, but there is no technical requirement to do this. You could call the welcome message just `welcomeMessage`, `MainMenu.welcomeMessage`, or `greeneggsandham.welcomeMessage`.

Comment: Just curious, do properties files have to be placed under `src/main/resources`? I can't seem to read it without placing it within the aforementioned directory.

Comment: @ky1emart yes, if you are using Maven. I can't remember about other project build systems at the moment but they might also have their own conventions.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned Android, which stores strings in XML format, you could do the same for your application too.

Using XML or JSON for your data would be a good idea as these can be easily parsed too.